# Setting DataSource to an array of Datarows in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am having difficulty finding anything that addresses an issue I am having. This code works just fine.

```
    cmbEmployee.DisplayMember = "FullName"
    cmbEmployee.ValueMember = "EmployeeID"
    cmbEmployee.DataSource = ds.Tables("Employees")
```

Except I wanted to filter out the inactive employees, and re-order them, so I changed it to this:

```
    Dim dr() As DataRow = ds.Tables("Employees").Select("Active=True", "FirstName, LastName")
    cmbEmployee.DisplayMember = "FullName"
    cmbEmployee.ValueMember = "EmployeeID"
    cmbEmployee.DataSource = dr
```

However what displays in the combobox is not the FullName, it just displays `System.Data.DataRow` in each item. This seems like it should be pretty straightforward. Can anyone please explain to me what I am missing?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Framework 4.6.1 if that matters.

Comment: You could try copying the rows to a new datatable - `cmbEmployee.DataSource = dr.CopyToDataTable()` - and see if that helps.

Comment: @Mark - I did try that and got the exact same results. However, I did it a different way. Your way worked. If you want to add this as an answer I will mark it as best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the selected rows to a new DataTable and bind to that:

```
cmbEmployee.DataSource = dr.CopyToDataTable()
```